# Copy-free thread-safe Ring Buffer for Big Arrays

Tags: c++, vector, move-semantics, lock-free, circular-buffer

For signal processing on big arrays (10^7 elements), I use different threads connected with ring buffers. Sadly, too much time is just needed for copying the data to and out of the buffer. The current implementation is based on `boost::lockfree::spsc_queue`.

So I'm am searching for a solution to **swap the ownership** of the vectors between the threads and the buffer by using unique_ptr to the vectors (please see drawing attached: [swapping pointer between threads and the queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfPeT.png)).

Moving smart pointers doesn't fit my needs, because therefore I need to allocate memory during runtime constantly for new vector elements. That overhead is bigger than copying the data around.

Am I missing a flaw in that design?

Are there thread-safe or even lock-free ring buffer implementations allowing swap operations for push and pop?

**Edit:** I modified a locking ring buffer to swap `unique_ptr`. The performance boost is huge. Though it doesn't feel like a elegant solution. Any recommendations?

```
// https://github.com/embeddedartistry/embedded-resources/blob/master/examples/cpp/circular_buffer.cpp

#include <memory>
#include <mutex>

template <typename T, int SIZE>
class RingbufferPointer {
typedef std::unique_ptr<T> TPointer;
public:
    explicit RingbufferPointer() {
        // create objects
        for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
            buf_[i] = std::make_unique<T>();
        }
    }

    bool push(TPointer &item) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        if (full())
            return false;

        std::swap(buf_[head_], item);

        if (full_)
            tail_ = (tail_ + 1) % max_size_;

        head_ = (head_ + 1) % max_size_;
        full_ = head_ == tail_;

        return true;
    }

    bool pop(TPointer &item) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        if (empty())
            return false;

        std::swap(buf_[tail_], item);

        full_ = false;
        tail_ = (tail_ + 1) % max_size_;

        return true;
    }

    void reset() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        head_ = tail_;
        full_ = false;
    }

    bool empty() const {
        return (!full_ && (head_ == tail_));
    }

    bool full() const {
        return full_;
    }

    int capacity() const {
        return max_size_;
    }

    int size() const {
        int size = max_size_;

        if(!full_) {
            if(head_ >= tail_)
                size = head_ - tail_;
            else
                size = max_size_ + head_ - tail_;
        }

        return size;
    }

private:
    TPointer buf_[SIZE];

    std::mutex mutex_;
    int head_ = 0;
    int tail_ = 0;
    const int max_size_ = SIZE;
    bool full_ = 0;
};
```

Comment: The mentioned boost queue has a very strict approach to push and pop elements and AFAIK does not allow to acquire a element, process it and release it for overwriting. Maybe you mix the pool approach with Mike answer.
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/52204403/9293869

Comment: not understand (for me) for what you need **swap** pointers or elements inside circular-buffer. are you have single producer and consumer ? if yes, why producer can not read data direct to write position and consumer direct process data from read position.

Comment: are you need exactly process items in FIFO order ? anyway this can be done with lock-free code without any mutex

Comment: @RdMm: Yes, only SPSC in FIFO order. What do you mean with writing directly to the FIFO? You can this be thread-safe? What happens if the consumer wants to access the write position while it's written? How do I block that access but still get a thread-safe or even lock-free queue?

Comment: @luxderfux - understand, possible implement SPSC in FIFO order. tread-safe and lock-free. without any mutex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Moving smart pointers doesn't fit my needs, because therefore I need
>   to allocate memory during runtime constantly for new vector elements.

Not necessarily true if you pre-allocate enough storage and implement your own memory management a la *simple segregated storage*, a.k.a *pooling*.

If you do that, there's nothing keeping you from swapping around and you get to keep your existing architecture using any *ring-buffer* that supports swapping of elements and remain with the same thread-safety you had before. You can check the option of just [using `boost::pool`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/interfaces.html) instead of implementing your own.

Comment: Great idea. Usually I set the sizes of my vectors during initialization. So with the pooling approach I save the time for allocation but have to reinitialize again. The overall measured performance boost using pooling is negligible.
So I have to keep my objects alive. Is there another suitable approach?

Comment: @luxderfux Wait, what exactly will you have to reinitialize?

Comment: Using vectors, I set the size in my constructors like this:
`boost::object_pool<std::vector<float>> pool{10000000, 0};
std::vector<float> *vec = pool.construct(1000000);`

Or do I missunderstand the concept?

Comment: @luxderfux OK that's already in the direction I was aiming with this answer. So you're looking for *another suitable approach* that would improve on this in what way?

Comment: So as I understood: The pooling helps me to pre-allocate memory and make it faster to access during runtime. But still the initialization of the class members is a expensive task due to sizing of vectors. Maybe it's possible to keep the objects alive in some kind of container which allows borrowing and returning of those objects. Or is there another way for fast initialization of vectors?

Comment: What I meant by pooling is exactly that: You never delete anything, just returning it to the pool for the next request to take it (take the same physical, pre-allocated and already initialized object) -- Let me know if you want me to elaborate so I'll just add it to the original answer.

Comment: Yes please, that sounds promising :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179648/discussion-between-skepticalempiricist-and-luxderfux).

Comment: @luxderfux Sorry I wrote back to you in the discussion (a long while ago) but not sure how this works... Comment was: OK so to do that I need to have firm understanding of your scenario: According to your drawing your producer pushes an entire big vector into the queue, and it stays there until the consumer pops it in its entirety, right? If so, then the objects you'll be swapping are the vectors themselves, right? When you talk about the initialization of class members, you mean the members of each element in the vector?

Comment: Thanks for asking. The big vector was the simplest case. In the end, I want to pass objects around that capsulate big arrays. I managed to build a quick and dirty pool container that fits my needs so far. So thank you for the idea of combining the queue with the pool. Seems to work :)

Answer (score 1):

if i correct understand your task - you need 2 containers:

- Thread-safe and lock-free pool for free elements - for not allocate /
  free it every time. pushing and popping is wait-free.
- Thread-safe and lock-free single-writer/single-reader *FIFO* queue,
  pushing and popping is wait-free.

with this you can do next:

- at begin you allocate `N` elements and push it to pool.
- Producer pop free item from pool (instead allocate memory)
- prepare item data
- push it to *FIFO* queue
- if no free items in pool - wait signal from Consumer

---

- Consumer pop item from *FIFO* queue
- process item data
- push item back to pool (instead free it memory)
- if queue is empty - wait signal from producer

---

*FIFO* queue can implement in next way:

```
class CyclicBufer
{
    struct alignas(8) Position 
    {
        ULONG _begin, _data_size;
    };

    std::atomic<Position> _pos;
    void** _items;

    ULONG _buf_size;

public:

    // Requires: only one thread is allowed to push data to the CyclicBufer
    bool push(void* item, bool* bWasEmpty = 0);

    // Requires: only one thread is allowed to pop data to the CyclicBufer
    bool pop(void** pitem, bool* bNotEmpty = 0);

    ~CyclicBufer()
    {
        if (_items)
        {
            delete [] _items;
        }
    }

    CyclicBufer() : _items(0), _buf_size(0)
    {
        _pos._My_val._begin = 0, _pos._My_val._data_size = 0;
    }

    bool create(ULONG buf_size)
    {
        if (_items = new(std::nothrow) void*[buf_size])
        {
            _buf_size = buf_size;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    bool is_empty()
    {
        Position current_pos = _pos.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);

        return !current_pos._data_size;
    }
};

bool CyclicBufer::push(void* item, bool* bWasEmpty /*= 0*/)
{
    Position current_pos = _pos.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);

    if (current_pos._data_size >= _buf_size) return false;

    // (_pos._begin + _pos._data_size) % _buf_size never changed in pop
    _items[(current_pos._begin + current_pos._data_size) % _buf_size] = item;

    for (;;)
    {
        Position new_pos = {
            current_pos._begin, current_pos._data_size + 1
        };

        if (_pos.compare_exchange_weak(current_pos, new_pos, std::memory_order_release))
        {
            if (bWasEmpty) *bWasEmpty = current_pos._data_size == 0;
            return true;
        }
    }
}

bool CyclicBufer::pop(void** pitem, bool* bNotEmpty /*= 0*/)
{
    Position current_pos = _pos.load(std::memory_order_acquire);

    if (!current_pos._data_size) return false;

    // current_pos._begin never changed in push
    void* item = _items[current_pos._begin];

    for (;;)
    {
        Position new_pos = {
            (current_pos._begin + 1) % _buf_size, current_pos._data_size - 1
        };

        if (_pos.compare_exchange_weak(current_pos, new_pos, std::memory_order_relaxed))
        {
            if (bNotEmpty) *bNotEmpty = new_pos._data_size != 0;
            *pitem = item;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

for Thread-safe and lock-free pool [implementation](https://kukuruku.co/post/lock-free-stack-for-windows/) on windows can be used [`InterlockedPushEntrySList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/interlockedapi/nf-interlockedapi-interlockedpushentryslist) and [`InterlockedPopEntrySList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/interlockedapi/nf-interlockedapi-interlockedpopentryslist), but of course possible implement this api and yourself:

```
struct list_entry {
    list_entry *Next;
};

#if defined(_M_X64) || defined(_M_ARM64)
#define MACHINE_64
#endif

struct alignas(sizeof(PVOID)*2) list_head 
{  
    union {
        struct {
            INT_PTR DepthAndSequence;
            union {
                list_entry* NextEntry;
                INT_PTR iNextEntry;
            };
        };
        __int64 value; // for 32-bit only
    };

    void init()
    {
        iNextEntry = 0, DepthAndSequence = 0;
    }

    bool push(list_entry* entry)
    {
        list_head current = { { DepthAndSequence, NextEntry } }, new_head;

        for (;;)
        {
            entry->Next = current.NextEntry;
            new_head.NextEntry = entry;
            new_head.DepthAndSequence = current.DepthAndSequence + 0x10001;

#ifdef MACHINE_64
            if (_INTRIN_RELEASE(_InterlockedCompareExchange128)(
                &DepthAndSequence, 
                new_head.iNextEntry, new_head.DepthAndSequence, 
                &current.DepthAndSequence))
            {
                // return is list was empty before push
                return !current.NextEntry;
            }
#else
            new_head.value = _INTRIN_RELEASE(_InterlockedCompareExchange64)(
                &value, new_head.value, current.value);

            if (new_head.value == current.value)
            {
                // return is list was empty before push
                return !current.NextEntry;
            }

            current.value = new_head.value;
#endif
        }
    }

    list_entry* pop()
    {
        list_head current = { { DepthAndSequence, NextEntry } }, new_head;

        for (;;)
        {
            list_entry* entry = current.NextEntry;

            if (!entry)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            // entry must be valid memory
            new_head.NextEntry = entry->Next;
            new_head.DepthAndSequence = current.DepthAndSequence - 1;

#ifdef MACHINE_64
            if (_INTRIN_ACQUIRE(_InterlockedCompareExchange128)(&DepthAndSequence, 
                new_head.iNextEntry, new_head.DepthAndSequence, 
                &current.DepthAndSequence))
            {
                return entry;
            }
#else
            new_head.value = _INTRIN_ACQUIRE(_InterlockedCompareExchange64)(
                &value, new_head.value, current.value);

            if (new_head.value == current.value)
            {
                return entry;
            }

            current.value = new_head.value;
#endif
        }
    }
};

#pragma warning(disable : 4324)

template <class _Ty>
class FreeItems : list_head
{
    void* _items;

    union Chunk {
        list_entry entry;
        char buf[sizeof(_Ty)];
    };

public:

    ~FreeItems()
    {
        if (_items)
        {
            delete [] _items;
        }
    }

    FreeItems() : _items(0)
    {
        init();
    }

    bool create(ULONG count)
    {
        if (Chunk* items = new(std::nothrow) Chunk[count])
        {
            _items = items;

            union {
                list_entry* entry;
                Chunk* item;
            };

            item = items;

            do 
            {
                list_head::push(entry);

            } while (item++, --count);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    _Ty* pop()
    {
        return (_Ty*)list_head::pop();
    }

    bool push(_Ty* item)
    {
        return list_head::push((list_entry*)item);
    }
};
```

with this 2 containers demo/test code can look like (*code for windows, but main - how we using pool and queue*)

```
struct BigData 
{
    ULONG _id;
};

struct CPData : CyclicBufer, FreeItems<BigData>
{
    HANDLE _hDataEvent, _hFreeEvent, _hConsumerStop, _hProducerStop;

    ULONG _waitReadId, _writeId, _setFreeCount, _setDataCount;

    std::_Atomic_integral_t _dwRefCount;
    bool _bStop;

    static ULONG WINAPI sProducer(void* This)
    {
        reinterpret_cast<CPData*>(This)->Producer();
        reinterpret_cast<CPData*>(This)->Release();
        return __LINE__;
    }

    void Producer()
    {
        HANDLE Handles[] = { _hProducerStop, _hFreeEvent  };

        for (;;)
        {
            BigData* item;

            while (!_bStop && (item = FreeItems::pop()))
            {
                // init data item
                item->_id = _writeId++;

                bool bWasEmpty;

                if (!CyclicBufer::push(item, &bWasEmpty)) __debugbreak();

                if (bWasEmpty)
                {
                    _setDataCount++;
                    SetEvent(_hDataEvent);
                }
            }

            switch (WaitForMultipleObjects(2, Handles, FALSE, INFINITE))
            {
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                SetEvent(_hConsumerStop);
                return;
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:
                break;
            default:
                __debugbreak();
            }
        }
    }

    static ULONG WINAPI sConsumer(void* This)
    {
        reinterpret_cast<CPData*>(This)->Consumer();
        reinterpret_cast<CPData*>(This)->Release();
        return __LINE__;
    }

    void Consumer()
    {
        HANDLE Handles[] = { _hDataEvent, _hConsumerStop };

        for (;;)
        {
            switch (WaitForMultipleObjects(2, Handles, FALSE, INFINITE))
            {
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                break;
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:
                return;
            default:
                __debugbreak();
            }

            bool bNotEmpty;

            do 
            {
                BigData* item;

                if (!CyclicBufer::pop((void**)&item, &bNotEmpty)) __debugbreak();

                // check FIFO order
                if (item->_id != _waitReadId) __debugbreak();

                _waitReadId++;

                // process item

                // free item to the pool
                if (FreeItems::push(item))
                {
                    // stack was empty
                    _setFreeCount++;
                    SetEvent(_hFreeEvent);
                }

            } while (bNotEmpty);
        }
    }

    ~CPData()
    {
        if (_hConsumerStop) CloseHandle(_hConsumerStop);
        if (_hProducerStop) CloseHandle(_hProducerStop);
        if (_hFreeEvent) CloseHandle(_hFreeEvent);
        if (_hDataEvent) CloseHandle(_hDataEvent);

        if (_waitReadId != _writeId || !CyclicBufer::is_empty()) __debugbreak();

        DbgPrint("%s(%u %u %u)\n", __FUNCTION__, _writeId, _setFreeCount, _setDataCount);
    }

public:

    CPData()
    {
        _hFreeEvent = 0, _hDataEvent = 0, _hProducerStop = 0, _hConsumerStop = 0;
        _waitReadId = 0, _writeId = 0, _dwRefCount = 1;
        _setFreeCount = 0, _setDataCount = 0, _bStop = false;
    }

    void AddRef()
    {
        _MT_INCR(_dwRefCount);
    }

    void Release()
    {
        if (!_MT_DECR(_dwRefCount))
        {
            delete this;
        }
    }

    ULONG Create(ULONG n)
    {
        if (!CyclicBufer::create(n) || !FreeItems::create(n))
        {
            return ERROR_NO_SYSTEM_RESOURCES;
        }

        return (_hDataEvent = CreateEvent(0, FALSE, FALSE, 0)) &&
            (_hFreeEvent = CreateEvent(0, FALSE, FALSE, 0)) &&
            (_hProducerStop = CreateEvent(0, TRUE, FALSE, 0)) &&
            (_hConsumerStop = CreateEvent(0, TRUE, FALSE, 0)) ? 0 : GetLastError();
    }

    ULONG StartThread(bool bConsumer)
    {
        AddRef();

        if (HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, bConsumer ? sConsumer : sProducer, this, 0, 0))
        {
            CloseHandle(hThread);
            return 0;
        }

        Release();

        return GetLastError();
    }

    ULONG Stop()
    {
        ULONG err = SetEvent(_hProducerStop) ? 0 : GetLastError();
        _bStop = true;
        return err;
    }
};

void BufTest()
{
    if (CPData* p = new CPData)
    {
        if (!p->Create(16))
        {
            if (!p->StartThread(false))
            {
                p->StartThread(true);
            }

            MessageBoxW(0, 0, L"Wait Stop", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            p->Stop();
        }
        p->Release();
    }
    MessageBoxW(0,0,0,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although `boost::lockfree::spsc_queue` lacks move support, you can still do that.

Example that moves vectors into and from the queue:

```
struct Element {
    std::vector<int> data_;

    Element(std::vector<int>& data)
        : data_(std::move(data))
    {}

    Element(Element const&) = delete;
    Element operator=(Element const&) = delete;

    operator std::vector<int>&&() {
        return std::move(data_);
    }
};

int main() {
    boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<Element, boost::lockfree::capacity<2>> q;

    std::vector<int> a(1);
    assert(!a.empty());
    q.push(&a, &a + 1); // Move the vector into the queue.
    assert(a.empty());

    std::vector<int> b = q.front(); // Move the vector from queue.
    assert(!b.empty());
    q.pop();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One technique I have used is this...

```
void next_step(std::vector<std::string> &a)
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.swap(a);
    // process vector ...
}
```

No swapping or copying of individual elements.  Fast and efficient.

Mike

Comment: But he mentions that he got no time for creating those object anyway beforehand. Even if he swap the ressources, he cannot swap it the ressources back into the process at the end.

Comment: @JackGrinningCat This technique avoids creating anything except an empty vector. This is almost zero overhead. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Are you sure. The memory acquired from a will be freed at the end of next_step in (thread 2) and without a pool has to be acquired thread 1. If not at the end of thread 2 at least at the end of signal processing chain

Comment: @JackGrinningCat Of course part of the processing is to pass the vector on to the following step in a similar fashion, either directly or by the existing system of ring buffers.

Comment: `std::vector::swap` is not thread-safe / lock-free.  `std::vector` implementations typically have 3 pointers (start/end/used), so only x86-64 with 32-bit pointers (like the x32 ABI) even could do a lock-free swap using 16-byte `cmpxchg16b` in some hypothetical implementation that wanted to provide an `atomic_replace()` method that atomically replaced all the members.

Comment: Even with mutex protection, swap is fast enough that the swap time is insignificant when compared to alternatives.